# log4j 2 RollingFileAppender deleting content of log

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

The following configuration is supposed to create a new log file everyday:

```
<configuration status="trace">
  <appenders>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="../logs/excepciones.log" filePattern="../logs/excepciones.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
     <PatternLayout>
       <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
     </PatternLayout>
     <Policies>
       <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
     </Policies>
   </RollingFile>
 </appenders>
 <loggers>

   <root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
   </root>
   <root level="info">
     <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
   </root>
 </loggers>
</configuration>
```

I do get a new file every day in the form `excepciones.log-yyyy-MM-dd`, the problem is that this new file contains only the last line that was inserted to `excepciones.log` before it was rolled to `excepciones.log-yyyy-MM-dd`, but I can't seem to figure out why. What I want is the whole content of today's log to be copied into a new file at 12:00 am.

So for example, yesterday, my log's content was:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
```

Today, that file has been renamed to `excepciones.log-2014-07-07, but its content is now:

```
this is line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of log4j2 are you using? Your problem description reminds me of [LOG4J2-531](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-531) which was fixed in log4j2-rc1.